# How remove leading zeroes in sql before using in where condition?

Tags: sql

I have two tables first one has numeric account number : **account_numeric**
I have another table which is has character account number : **account_char**

I am using a joining the tables using  where in such a way that :
Where account_numeric= account_char
But when I converted the account char before using in where condition it has been added with leading zeroes so I want to remove the leading zeroes in the newly changed from character to numeric and then you use where condition , so that I can get all values are matching .
( the appending of zeroes is happening she to the there are account number of different sizes)
**Could you guys please help me what function I should use to remove the leading zeroes please ?**

Comment: What database are you using (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres etc) ? Do you have only numeric values ? Are you worried about performance ?

Comment: Why... why any database designer would so such a thing... It just leads to a lot of extra effort everywhere. It's just nonsense.

Comment: @GabrielDurac sqlserver

Comment: @TheImpaler could you tell me why this is extra effort Iam a beginner , could you tell me an alternate way I can use please ..?

Comment: @user13365072 Simply because it's an error prone strategy. You'll need to remember to perform these conversion every time you compare the values. Now, if you forget, the database silently may perform the conversion for you... in the wrong direction. Moreover, the next developer that works with the project won't know that he/she needs to perform this conversion. In sum, you are creating an artificial problem and there's no reason for it.

Comment: But db didn’t convert it when I used in where condition it pointed at they should be of same data type .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `account_char` has only numeric values you could use `CAST(account_char as integer)` to get rid of your leading zeroes.

That being said, doing a join `ON table1.account_numeric=CAST(table2.account_char as integer)` is not a sargable way of writing a query and will not perform that well.

I would redesign the tables to either both use the char version or the numeric version.